# How to define minimum and maximum axis values in a flutter chart?

Tags: flutter, charts

I have a bubble chart (ScatterPlotChart) like the one below and I would like to change the values 0 on the x-axis and 0 on the y-axis to another value. I would like to change maximum values too.

[image: Scatter Plot Chart]

I've been going through the documentation and examples that appear at [Flutter Gallery Charts](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/gallery.html) but I can't find how to change these values.

I'm using charts_flutter (as charts) and the code where I define the ticks of the axes is as follows:

```
charts.ScatterPlotChart (
       seriesList,
       primaryMeasureAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec (
         tickProviderSpec: new charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec (desiredMaxTickCount: 2,),
        
       ),  
       domainAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec (
         tickProviderSpec: new charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec (desiredTickCount: 2,),
       ),
...
```

Is it possible to change the minimum and maximum values of the x and y axes in flutter graphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `zeroBound: false` on the BasicNumericTickProviderSpec. Something like:

```
  tickProviderSpec: new charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(
     desiredTickCount: 2, 
     zeroBound: false
  ),
```